# SQL: tricky question for finding lockout dates

Tags: sql, netezza

Hope you can help.  We have a table with two columns Customer_ID and Trip_Date.  The customer receives 15% off on their first visit and on every visit where they haven't received the 15% off offer in the past thirty days.  How do I write a single SQL query that finds all days where a customer received 15% off?

The table looks like this

```
+-----+-------+----------+
| Customer_ID | date     |
+-----+-------+----------+
|          1  | 01-01-17 |
|          1  | 01-17-17 |
|          1  | 02-04-17 |
|          1  | 03-01-17 |
|          1  | 03-15-17 |
|          1  | 04-29-17 |
|          1  | 05-18-17 |
+-----+-------+----------+
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
+-----+-------+----------+--------+----------+
| Customer_ID | date     | received_discount |
+-----+-------+----------+--------+----------+
|          1  | 01-01-17 |        1          |
|          1  | 01-17-17 |        0          |
|          1  | 02-04-17 |        1          |
|          1  | 03-01-17 |        0          |
|          1  | 03-15-17 |        1          |
|          1  | 04-29-17 |        1          |
|          1  | 05-18-17 |        0          |
+-----+-------+----------+--------+----------+
```

We are doing this work in Netezza.  I can't think of a way using just window functions, only using recursion and looping.  Is there some clever trick that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,
GF

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show sample data, sample output, and the code you wrote that produced the incorrect result. Also, pick 1 RDBMS as a tag.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? What did you try? and please post also sample dara and expected results as _formatted text_.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what your backend is, nor you gave some sample data and expected output nor you gave a sensible data schema :( This is an example based on guess of schema using postgreSQL as backend (would be too messy as a comment):
(I think you have Customer_Id, Trip_Date and LocationId in trips table?)

```
select * from trips t1
where not exists (
  select * from trips t2 
  where t1.Customer_id = t2.Customer_id and
  t1.Trip_Date > t2.Trip_Date 
  and t1.Trip_date - t2.Trip_Date < 30
);
```

Comment: This is good logic, but I think the OP wants a flag rather than a filter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, then OP can change it to an update query but when I wrote this OP didn't have any schema, sample output, thus no field to update. Shot in dark IOW.